# React useContext not triggering a re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context, use-context

I have set a three part Component for a filter menu. Component A) is the createContext which has an object with my globalData data and a function setData to change the data. When setData is triggered it retrieves data from the DB and updates the my globalData.data. Component B) Triggers component A and passes the appropriate values (This part works). Component C) is the useContext where it retrieves the data and users .Provider to display the data.

The problem is that Component C does not re-render any component.

Component A) Creates context and function to change context

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import APIEndpoint from 'src/js/api/apAPIEndpoint.js';

const globalData={data:{kpi:[]}, filters:{date:'', login:'9166', country:[], city:[]}, setData:(field, value)=>{

    globalData.filters = {...globalData.filters,[field]:value};
    let fetchURL = `/APIURL?alias=${parseInt(globalData.filters.login)}&${globalData.filters.country.map((item)=>('country='+item.country)).join('&')}&${globalData.filters.city.map((item)=>('city='+item.city)).join('&')}`;

    if(globalData.filters.login && globalData.filters.country.length>0 && globalData.filters.city.length>0){
      APIEndpoint
        .get(fetchURL)
        .then(res => {
          globalData.data={...globalData, data:res.data.data};
        });
    }
  }
};
const GlobalDataContext = createContext(globalData);

export default GlobalDataContext;
```

Component B) Triggers context change in (A)

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import GlobalDataContext from '/GlobalDataContext';

const globalData = useContext( GlobalDataContext );
const setGlobalData = globalData ? globalData.setData : null;
...
return(
<div>
<StyledSelect
onChange={(value) =>{
          setGlobalData(props.valueField, value);
        }} />
</div>
)
```

Component C) This is where it does not re-render. only want to re render one component  under Section 2

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import GlobalDataContext from '/GlobalDataContext';
const {data, setData} = useContext( GlobalDataContext );
...
return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        <title>Something - Home</title>
      </Helmet>
      <StencilResponsiveDesign sizes={[VIEWPORT_SIZES.S, VIEWPORT_SIZES.M]}>
        ...
      {/* Section 1 */}
              <FilterBar />
              <Spacer height={50} />

      {/* Section 2 */}
              <GlobalDataContext.Provider value={globalData.data.kpi}> 
                <div>
                  <KpiWidget />
                </div>
              </GlobalDataContext.Provider>
```

Comment: In your code examples, the calls to `useContext` are right next to the imports. Is that how it is in the real code? Or is use `useContext` being used inside the components?

Comment: globalData is not a piece of state, if you want to trigger an update globalData should be created by `const [globalData, setGlobalData] = React.useState(YOUR_DEFAULT_STATE)`

Comment: When using useState it re-renders all the components. I am trying to make it only re-render the <KpiWidget /> component

Comment: Just made edits to my post (C) for clarification. I am trying to re render the components in Section 2 only.